# How to print a function definition in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have defined a few different functions in my `.bash_profile`. I usually remember the name of function but want to take a quick peek in the code before I run it.

In my `.bash_profile` I have the following:

```
gpm () {
  echo "git pull origin master"
  git pull origin master
}
```

Now I want to run something like this in Bash:

```
$ <something> gpm
```

Result expected: Don't execute the function just print out the function definition itself.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

EDIT: The best answer isn't this one, but the other one below.

What this answer used to say is that you can get a function definition in bash using the `type` builtin, e.g. `type gpm`. However, using `declare` as described in the other answer is better in every way.

Comment: Although 'declare' is in general better for script processing, for frequent command line use I do prefer 'type', as I only <type> four letters!

Comment: I actually prefer `type gpm` because this can be used to show functions or aliases... very useful when you have a lot of custom shortcuts

Answer (score 102):

`declare -f gpm` will just print the function definition of function `gpm` with no other text.

Comment: +1 - Better than `type` since it doesn't print the "gpm is a function" line.

Comment: Just noting `declare`'s not available in stock OSX.

Comment: @hlfcoding: why do you think that? It's a shell builtin and even the ancient versions of bash which comes shipped with Mac OS have it.

Comment: declare (alone) will also print all the functions - which afaikt type can't do.

Comment: Note: in `ksh` and kornshell clones, `typeset` essentually performs the same actions as `declare`.

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: Note #2: Also in `ksh` (at least ksh93), if you do `typeset -f` you'll get a list of all user-defined functions and their definitions. If you instead do `typeset -f <functionname>`, you'll get just the definition of the function `<functionname>`. This _also_ works in bash!

Comment: In `bash` `typeset` is an alias of `declare`. I agree that this answer is much more correct, but it won't let me delete the accepted answer. I would if I could.

Comment: [humour] Wow, I hope your guilt has not been weighing you down for the past 8 years [/humour] ;)

Comment: No guilt, just hoping some higher-rep user might notice and be able to improve the situation by deleting my post and making this the accepted answer. It's just better information.